# R Raster: Why do the cropped GeoTIFF rasters have different values than the original rasters (the values are rounded)?

Tags: r, raster, crop, rgdal, geotiff

I have an interesting problem with the crop function. When I crop a stack of my rasters, the resulting files have different values from the original files - values are rounded. Interestingly, when I do this in QGIS, I don't have this problem. For example, below I am pasting the values read from individual rasters using the tool **sample raster values** in QGIS:

| Original raster | Cropped in R | Cropped in QGIS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -1,649999999999980 | -2,000000000000000 | -1,649999999999980 |
| 0,850000000000023 | 1,000000000000000 | 0,850000000000023 |
| -1,649999999999980 | -2,000000000000000 | -1,649999999999980 |
| -1,149999999999980 | -1,000000000000000 | -1,149999999999980 |
| -4,049999999999960 | -4,000000000000000 | -4,049999999999960 |
| -3,049999999999950 | -3,000000000000000 | -3,049999999999950 |

Here is my code:

```
require(raster)
require(rgdal)
rasterOptions(tmpdir="C:/GIS/Temp", progress="text", timer=TRUE)
setwd("C:/GIS/Saved")
maska <- readOGR(dsn="C:/GIS/Mask", layer="Europe")
pliki_chelsa<- list.files("C:/GIS/Chelsa 2.1/1981-2010/bio/1",pattern='tif',full.names=TRUE)
stack_chelsa <- raster::stack(pliki_chelsa)
crs(stack_chelsa) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
nazwy_chelsa <- names(stack_chelsa)
maska_chelsa <- crop(stack_chelsa, maska)
writeRaster(maska_chelsa, filename=nazwy_chelsa, format="GTiff", prj=TRUE, bylayer=TRUE, suffix=nazwy_chelsa, overwrite=TRUE)
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Regards
Adrian